# Safari : "x console messages are not shown"

Tags: safari, console

I need to get information from some console.log(), however Safari just greets me with a "x(number) console messages are not shown." instead and so I'm stuck, yelling at the screen.

I cannot seem to find why, any ideas ? :)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

make sure you go to Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop Menu in Menu Bar. Then you can pull up the console with Command+Option+C.

Comment: I had this problem too, but it was IN the console that I saw "100 console messages are not shown". Since this question ranks highly in Google for this problem, it would be good to supply a real answer.

Comment: Why is this the correct answer? This doesn't answer the question. Command+Option+C shows the console, with the "console messages not shown" message hiding everything I need to see..

This is, in fact, the sole Google result returned for 'safari "console messages not shown"'. A correct answer would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue while trying to look at `console.log` from an extension's background page console (not sure if this is what you are trying to do).
It seems that it's logs that happen before the actual console window is opened.

A workaround I found was to have the console window opened, and press `CMD-r` to refresh the extension (while inspecting the background page), then all the logs would show up.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. So I upgraded macOS to fix it. 13 -> 14.